# Is there any way to call a specific variable based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to call a certain variable based off which variable the user asked for. 
I'm aware I can use if/else statements but I feel like there's a better way. In the last line of my code, I want the input variables in the curly braces to complete the variable call. 
Sorry if this was a poor explanation as it's hard to explain.

```
class Bed:
    def __init__(self, size, color, price):
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.price = price

    def bed_size(self):
        print('This bed is {}'.format(self.size))

    def bed_color(self):
        print('This bed is {}'.format(self.color))

    def bed_price(self):
        print('This bed is {}'.format(self.price))


king_bed = Bed('very big', 'turquoise', '$1000')
queen_bed = Bed("medium size", 'magenta', '$700')
twin_bed = Bed('quite small', 'azure', '$400')

bed = input('Which of our fine beds would you like to gain more knowledge of? The king, queen or twin bed?')
attribute = input("Would you like to know the price, size or color?")

{bed}_bed.bed_{attribute}()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is by defining a dictionary and using the built-in [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
class Bed:
    def __init__(self, size, color, price):
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.price = price

    def print_size(self):
        print('This bed is {}'.format(self.size))

    def print_color(self):
        print('This bed is {}'.format(self.color))

    def print_price(self):
        print('This bed is {}'.format(self.price))


beds = {
    'king': Bed('very big', 'turquoise', '$1000'),
    'queen':  Bed("medium size", 'magenta', '$700'),
    'twin': Bed('quite small', 'azure', '$400'),
}

which = input('Which of our fine beds would you like to gain more knowledge of,\n'
              'the king, queen or twin bed? ')
attribute = input("Would you like to know the price, size or color? ")

getattr(beds[which], 'print_' + attribute)()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec()`, it will convert a string to a python code.

Example 1:

```
string = "print('Hello world')"
exec(string)
```

Output:

```
Hello world
```

Example 2:

```
num = input("Enter your number: ")
exec("result = %s + 12")
print("The answer is " + result)
```

Output:

```
Enter your number: 6
The answer is 18
```